# How to get a git diff for a file in a pre-receive hook between the current HEAD and the newest file from the push?

Tags: git, diff, hook, gitolite

How do I get a `git diff` in a pre-receive hook between A and B?

- A. (newest version of `somefile.ext` as viewed in) current HEAD on server
- B. (newest version of `somefile.ext` as viewed in) received tree from pre-receive hook

I need this, because when some files change (on a Gitolite server), we like to be notified and see the difference between A and B by e-mail.

Environment: Ubuntu server 11 + Gitolite + pre-receive hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually want to use post-receive, as pre-receive is mostly used to reject updates and post-receive for notifications (which seems what you want to do).

Both get the same input (through stdin) and it's documented in [githooks(5)](http://gitmanual.org/githooks.html#pre-receive)
The input is a list of updated refs and their old and new commit hashes.
You could use this data to do your `git diff`